# nmap: Couldn't open a raw socket. Error: Permission denied (13)

Tags: ssh, permissions, socket, privileges, nmap

I'm attempting to run the following command on an Ubuntu box (ssh from Windows 10 PowerShell):

```
sudo nmap -sU -O localhost

Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-02 10:13 GMT
Couldn't open a raw socket. Error: Permission denied (13)
```

My expectation was that `sudo` would be enough for this.

Is there a directory I need to change the write permission of?

Is there anything obvious I could do to resolve this?

Comment: @Panki thanks, but I'm running the command on a ubuntu box, so surely the linux version is what I want?

Comment: Oh from win10 powershell, sorry I'm dumb. I read that as WSL. Nevermind.

Comment: @Panki No problem, thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: @A.B this was (is still a bit) true. I thought commands I was running would be exactly as if they are run on a bash terminal on the ubuntu box

Comment: In the end I installed nmap for windows and ran it with the Ubuntu box as target

Comment: @A.B How would I know for sure I'm using it? Is `ssh` in power shell always WSL? Are the commands I type once sshed in also WSL?

Comment: Just explain how you installed Ubuntu. This should cover it.

Comment: @A.B From iso on usb (it's a physically separate machine)

Comment: ok then you are not using WSL on the Ubuntu system. Then I wonder why you accepted an answer about WSL

Comment: And why you added back the tag without understanding what it means... oh well I'm leaving it here

Comment: @A.B due to general confusion over what WSL was doing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Couldn't open a raw socket. Error: Permission denied (13)

Because the raw sockets in WSL isn't fully supported.

Try this fix on [WSL; NMAP not work!](https://www.stenge.info/post/wsl-nmap-not-work)

> But now you can "fix it" typing this command on WSL:

> ```
> alias nmap='"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Nmap/nmap.exe"'
> ```

> Stay tuned on the path of your Windows file.